# How can I keep track which person has added which data to a database?

Tags: java, android

I have an app where anyone who downloads the app can add data to the database. The data THEY added will get displayed in a listView for only them to see. The users don't have to register an account or anything. Now when multiple people use the app, different data gets added to the database. So my question is, what are good ways to differentiate data, so the person who added data, only sees the data they added.

I have two ideas, either add the data ID to sharedpreferences, so when I select the data from the database, I select data where the data ID equals to the one in sharedpreferences OR when I add the data to the database, I add a unique key, so I can select * where unique key equals x.

I like the second idea more, but what would be a good unique key to use. I've thought of using

```
private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

but is that a reliable solution, are there any other unique key solutions I could use?

Any feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: If no login is required, then does the app asks for an alias each time an user starts using it?  It's easy job to determine the device each time but the hard part is to guess which of the users using the device has requested the list this time...

Comment: Thanks @fardjad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best way to handle such cases is to generate a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) for each user.

Android itself will [help you generate one](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()).

You can generate the UUID the first time the app is launched, and store id in SharedPreferences.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking of! Thank you!